# Laptop not booting if sata controller set to AHCI

Tags: hard-drive, boot, sata, ahci, toshiba-laptop

I have Toshiba Satellite C660

Tried to install Windows7 by selecting Sata controller as AHCI I got this message

> Windows cannot be installed to this disk. This computers hardware may not support booting to this disk. Ensure that the disks controller is enabled in the computers BIOs menu.

Then I changed Sata controller to Compatibility which worked but OS running pathetically slow.

How can I use AHCI sata controller mode like I was using before?

Comment: You need to get the latest AHCI drivers.  Get **Slimdrivers** and have it find a current version for you.

Comment: Would you like to suggest me some perfect and my system specific source to get these drivers?

Comment: http://www.driverupdate.net/downloads/SlimDrivers-setup.exe    This should auto-detect what you need and give a download button which downloads and installs driver automatically.

Comment: @cybernard, I have downloaded all the drivers and SlimDrivers utility says all drivers up-to-date... Still I am facing bluescreen error after changing Sata controller to AHCI.

Comment: Ok since that was not enough.  Logged in as an **administrator** Start then Run or **<Windows key> and R** then type **sysprep /generalize**  Reboot and immediately go into bios and set it to AHCI mode.  Save changes and it will reboot.  Windows should then detect the new drivers.

Comment: @cybernard Thanks for replying.. I have done what you said and my system reinstalled all the drivers again.. after restarting windows with AHCI mode second time onwards my laptop keeps me showing "Black Screen" on startup, Pressing f8 has no effect.. sometimes I am getting an error on screen saying HDD failed to boot and redirects me to boot device selection window, I have seen this error many times when I had Win 7 installed on AHCI mode of Sata controller as a solution to this I used to restart windows so many times.